# Magento 2 actions column in backend grid registry.js error on click any collumn

Tags: module, grid, magento2.2.2, custom-column-grid

When I click anywhere on the Grid I get the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Actions xml:

```
...
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\BlogAction">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blog_id</item>
           </item>
      </argument>
 </actionsColumn>
 ...
```

BlogAction:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class BlogAction extends Column
{
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'vendor/blog/edit';


    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['blog_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    'blog_id' => $item['blog_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It seem that it's related to the `actionsColumn` as if I remove the xml then on click grid no error happen. I just can't figure it out what I am missing some sort of registry perhaps?

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found where the actual problem comes from and why the error occur.

It comes form inlineEdit editor config within `columns` I comment it out and the error is gone

e.g

```
...
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_columns.ids</item>
        <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blog_id</item>
    </item>
    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_index.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
    </item>
    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_columns.actions</item>
            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
            <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_blog_grid_index.vendor_blog_grid_index.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
            <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

...

Somewhere in here there's something not quite right!